# Return and display result of DML from SQL to C#

Tags: c#

I have a generic function in C#:

```
public bool fn(string nameOfProc, SqlParameter[] sqlParameters)
{
     SqlCommand s= new SqlCommand(nameOfProc);
     s.Connection = sqlConn;
     s.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     s.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);
     s.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It runs successfully in case of insert, update, and search. But I also want to display the changed rows after update or display the result of my search somewhere on UI or console with the same generic function. How to do that?

Comment: I don't believe an update will normally tell you *which* rows changed - just how many. And trying to write one method to handle multiple situations sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet: it *can* tell you which rows were updated when using the `OUTPUT` clause - but that's an extra step that needs to be taken - it's not done "automagically" for you

Comment: @marc_s: Right. I suspected there was *some* way of doing it (which may well vary by database).

Comment: With the `OUTPUT` clause being ANSI/ISO standard SQL, there's hope that more and more database systems will start supporting it (if they don't already do so)